# XLWings / Excel problems handling "multi-cell array formulas"

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlwings

## scope

I'm using XLWings for the obvious, to retrieve data from external sources, do a bit of transformation in Python, and then pump it into Excel.

I'm using UDFs to do so (Windows 10, Excel 2016 32bit).

The only way I'm aware of, is to use "multi-cell array formulas" to add the 2 dimensional data (Pandas dataframes) into Excel Worksheets.

## issue

The "multi-cell array formulas" seems to have a multiple limitations, which I have not found a solution, how to:

- handle dynamic sizes of the returning dataframe (which is the rule and not the exception, see my [comment on github](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/511#issuecomment-234969441) too)
- format as tables (not possible) to apply coloring, sorting and filtering
- add to datamodel (not possible) for i.e. joining
- (what else is not working?)

## question

How do other handle this?

Answer (score 1):

xlwings v0.10 introduces dynamic arrays, see the [release notes](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/whatsnew.html#dynamic-array-formulas).

Now you can do:

```
import xlwings as xw
import numpy as np

@xw.func
@xw.ret(expand='table')
def dynamic_array(r, c):
    return np.random.randn(int(r), int(c))
```

and you can use that formula by simply writing it into the top left cell, without the need to make it an Excel array formula.